# MySQL not using PHP variables properly in Queries, replacing the variables with strings/integers works fine

Tags: php, html, mysql, variables, plesk

MySQL is not using the variables as it should. it is not taking any value from them it is incrementing the auto-increment numbers in the MYSQL table, however the row is not saved. I am not given any errors.

I have tried like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `tbl_bike` (`userID`, `ManuPartNo`, `BikeManufacturer`, `BikeModel`, `BikeType`, `BikeWheel`, `BikeColour`, `BikeSpeed`, `BrakeType`, `FrameGender`, `AgeGroup`, `DistFeatures`) 
VALUES (“.$userID.”, “.$PartNo.”, “.$BikeManufacturer.”, “.$BikeModel.”, “.$BikeType.”, “.$BikeWheel.”, “.$BikeColour.”, “.$BikeSpeed.”, “.$BrakeType.”, “.$FrameGender.”, “.$AgeGroup.”, “.$DistFeatures.”)";
```

I have also tried replacing the " with ', Removing the . and even completely removing the ". Nothing has helped with this issue. When I use this query but remove the variables and instead put string, int etc in the correct places the query will function perfectly and put the results into the table. My variables are normally as follows:

```
$PartNo =  $_POST['ManuPartNo’];

$BikeManufacturer =  $_POST['BikeManufacturer’]; 

$BikeModel =  $_POST['BikeModel’]; 

$BikeType =  $_POST['BikeType’]; 

$BikeWheel =  $_POST['BikeWheel’]; 

$BikeColour =  $_POST['BikeColour’]; 

$BikeSpeed =  $_POST['BikeSpeed’]; 

$BrakeType =  $_POST['BrakeType’]; 

$FrameGender =  $_POST['FrameGender’]; 

$AgeGroup =  $_POST['AgeGroup’]; 

$DistFeatures =  $_POST['DistFeatures’];
```

These variables normally take input from a separate PHP/HTML file with the `'$_POST['DistFeatures’];'`

I have tried removing the `$_POST['DistFeatures’];` from the ends of each of them and just replacing the values with normal string or int values but still nothing helps. I am completely stuck and would appreciate any help with this.

This is all running on a plesk server.

Comment: Get rid of the special quote characters like “ in your query and replace with plain single or double quotes. If you are using VS Code code editor this should not be a problem. Also switch to using a PHP framework like Laravel, it will save you headaches later.

Comment: See about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries

Comment: @w.PatrickGale As I said in my post, I have tried with those special characters, single quotes and double quotes, still with no success.

Comment: @Strawberry I will be implementing prepared queries once I get the database to function properly

Comment: Proper implementation is often a shortcut to a working query

Comment: @Strawberry Is this a decent way of implementing it? ```$BikeModel = $mysqli -> real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['BikeModel']);```

Comment: No. This method is essentially redundant when using prepared and bound queries

Comment: @Strawberry Even so, there is no point doing all of this with the variables when the SQL won't take the values from the variable in the first place

Comment: Well, that's true, but that's not demonstrated by your question- only by your comment on whereisburak's answer

Comment: @Strawberry Apologies, it is my first time using StackOverflow and I wasn't sure how to word the question to make myself clear

Comment: You're comment regarding pdo doesn't really make sense

Comment: @Strawberry which part of it does not make sense?

Comment: Using MySQL doesn't preclude the use of PDO; it just precludes the use of PHP's mysql(i) API. Anyway, it doesn't matter so much whether you're using mysqli or PDO (although OOP enthusiasts would disagree). What matters is that you use prepared and bound queries.

Comment: @Strawberry this is a university assignment where we have been told that we have to do it like this. 
The main problem is still the variables not being used in the SQL statements still

Comment: I think you should edit your question and code, with the knowledge now in your possession.

Answer (score 3):

Please stop using deprecated MySQL. I will suggest an answer using PDO. You can use this to frame your other queries using PDO.

```
// Establish a connection in db.php (or your connection file)
$dbname = "dbname"; // your database name
$username = "root"; // your database username
$password = ""; // your database password or leave blank if none
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbport = "10832";

$dsn = "mysql:dbname=$dbname;host=$dbhost";
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);

// Include db.php on every page where queries are executed and perform queries the following way

// Take Inputs this way (your method is obsolete and will return "Undefined Index" error)

$userId = (!empty($_SESSION['sessionname']))?$_SESSION['sessionname']:null; // If session is empty it will be set to Null else the session value will be set
$PartNo = (!empty($_POST['ManuPartNo']))?$_POST['ManuPartNo']:null; // If post value is empty it will be set to Null else the posted value will be set
$BikeManufacturer = (!empty($_POST['BikeManufacturer']))?$_POST['BikeManufacturer']:null;
$BikeModel = (!empty($_POST['BikeModel']))?$_POST['BikeModel']:null;
$BikeType = (!empty($_POST['BikeType']))?$_POST['BikeType']:null;
$BikeWheel = (!empty($_POST['BikeWheel']))?$_POST['BikeWheel']:null;

// Query like this
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO(`userID`, `ManuPartNo`, `BikeManufacturer`, `BikeModel`, `BikeType`)VALUES(:uid, :manuptno, :bkman, :bkmodel, :bktype)");
$stmt-> bindValue(':uid', $userId);
$stmt-> bindValue(':manuptno', $PartNo);
$stmt-> bindValue(':bkman', $BikeManufacturer);
$stmt-> bindValue(':bkmodel', $BikeModel);
$stmt-> bindValue(':bktype', $BikeType);
$stmt-> execute();

if($stmt){
    echo "Row inserted";
}else{
    echo "Error!";
}
```

See, it's that simple. Use PDO from now on. It's more secured. To try this, just copy the whole code in a blank PHP file and and run it. Your database will receive an entry. Make sure to change your database values here.

Comment: I forgot to mention that while taking inputs of POST data you should use "0" instead of "null" at the end if in case the returned input is a number and not a string. For example, for post value of Phone Number it can be 0 instead of Null.

Comment: Note that an EDIT button is provided

Comment: Unfortunately I have to use MySQL for this project, otherwise I would use something else.

Answer (score -1):

You should try this

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_bike (userID, ManuPartNo, BikeManufacturer, BikeModel, BikeType, BikeWheel, BikeColour, BikeSpeed, BrakeType, FrameGender, AgeGroup, DistFeatures) VALUES ('$userID', '$PartNo', '$BikeManufacturer', '$BikeModel', '$BikeType', '$BikeWheel', '$BikeColour', '$BikeSpeed', '$BrakeType', '$FrameGender', '$AgeGroup', '$DistFeatures')";
```

If this doesn't work, enable the null property in sql values. So you can find out where the error originated.